# piggyback FTP over SSH tunnel

Tags: ftp, ssh-tunnel

I want to piggyback FTP over SSH tunnel to traverse the jump host. FileZilla as the client but don't wan't to use WinSCP. I tried SOCKS proxy, no succeed :(. Anyone here to assist please? Please see image below for more info

In this example, FTP server is 192.168.1.200 Jumphost into which I can make an SSH connection is: 10.10.10.40 My IP is: 172.16.1.1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyCd4.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is an easy way to do this, if there exists a way at all. FTP uses multiple TCP connection and only one of these has a fixed port. The connections for the data transfer are created dynamically and the port (and also IP address in most cases) used in these data connections is exchanged inside the control connection. If data and control connections are simply forwarded through some tunnel then the information about the port allocations do not reflect the real ports after the tunnel, i.e. a rewrite of the specific FTP commands and responses by the tunnel is needed. But, SSH only forwards connections and does not rewrite anything at the application level as required for FTP.

It would be better to use a less complex protocol, i.e. a protocol without such dynamic port allocations. Using SFTP  for example instead pf FTP/FTPS for data transfer would help. Of course, this requires a matching server at the other end and a normal FTP server would not do it.